# Running Perl Script With Java Exec

Tags: java, exec

The script I'm trying to run is  'root/tufimail'. The code below produces this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "root/tufimail": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
at rss.RSSFeedParser.main(RSSFeedParser.java:450)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax? Why is it not finding the file?

```
Runtime r= Runtime.getRuntime();
Process exec = r.exec("/root/tufimail \"<person@aplace.com; person2@aplace.com>\" \"Tesing 2 recipients\" \"I love booty\"");

  try {
        exec.waitFor();           
        System.out.println(exec.getOutputStream());
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RSSFeedParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null, ex);
    }
```

Here are the file properties:

```
Here is the linux directory :/root/tufimail
```

> ```
> [root@abox ~]# ls -l tufimail
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 595 Aug 20 14:35 tufimail
> ```

Comment: Are you running the java program as root? If not, there could be some permissions issues reading the /root folder.

Comment: (Removed "perl" tag since this has nothing to do with Perl.)

Comment: I don't think the arguments will work out the way you seem to expect -- the string is parsed _by whitespace_ first (via StringTokenizer class); so the program will get each word (`\"Testing`) as a separate argument while quotes imply that it should have phrases as arguments (`"Testing 2 reciipients"`). Try using an array with command and arguments, instead of a string.  (This shouldn't be related to the problem you are reporting though)

Comment: Error message says "root/tufimail" but that doesn't match the code, which starts with "/root" -- maybe that's a clue?

Comment: Your error message about a relative command name does not match your sample code. Are you sure you pasted both? If you specify a command name without leading slash you must be sure that the current working directory before starting Java is correct. Besides that using the argument array variant of ProcessBuilder is (a bit) easier to use - @zdim mentioned that (however it won’t be related to your exception as the first part is the correct command)